# Gradle doesn't pack JNI *.so libraries into APK file

Tags: java, android, ant, gradle, java-native-interface

I have pretty large source tree which includes JNI sources as well:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}    
sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            aidl.srcDirs=['src/main/aidl']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets']
            jni.srcDirs=[] //to suppress makefiles autogeneration
            //jni.srcDirs=['src/main/jni']
            jniLibs.srcDirs=['src/main/libs'] //native *.so in armeabi x86 and mips to include
        }
    }
}

//skipped

dependencies {
    apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0+'
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0+'
    compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':actionbarsherlocki18n')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-5.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.6.jar')
}
ant.importBuild 'src/main/jni/build_native.xml'  //ant task to build JNI
```

Everything works except Gradle doesn't put *.so files into final APK file. Ant really generates *.so libraries and put them into `src/main/libs/x86` and `src/main/libs/armeabi` folders - I have double checked it.

I'm really stuck with this issue - please help.

BTW: Merry X-Mas!

Comment: http://ph0b.com/android-studio-gradle-and-ndk-integration/  "integrate .so files into your apk"  should be relevant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key point in my case was:

```
compileSdkVersion 21  //instead 19
```

As soon as I have changed compileSdkVersion from 19 to 21 - problem was resolved (required also to change JDK 6 to JDK 7.

Magic...